# Integration of Accusoft and Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a service which registers the mime types that is being supported by accusoft. There are nearly more than 200 mime types supported by it.

Now i have to register all the 200 mime types one by one. Presently i'm doing something like this.

```
FVConfigProvider.register('application/pdf', accusoftHtml);
angular.module('moduleName')
     .config(['FVConfigProvider', function (FVConfigProvider) {
            FVConfigProvider.register('text/enriched', accusoftHtml);
                 register 2...
                 register 3...
                 ....4.....
                 ....5.....
                 .........
                ............
                   100
            );
        }]);
```

FVConfigProvider is a service which registers the mime types.
So if i need to register 100 mime types, i have to write 100 times with different mime types. 
Is there any other way to do it?

```
 //register: registers a custom viewer.
//  mimeType: The mimeType that the viewer is for.
//  html: The html that is to be used to render the viewer.
this.register = function (mimeType, html) {

    //Have to manually get the filter from the angular module.
    var injector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
    var filter = injector.get('$filter');
    var existingViewerMapping = filter('filter')(this.viewerMappings, {
        mimeType: mimeType
    })[0];

    if (existingViewerMapping) {
        existingViewerMapping.mimeType = mimeType;
        existingViewerMapping.html = html;
    } else {
        this.viewerMappings.push({
            mimeType: mimeType,
            html: html
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Post the FVConfigProvider code

Comment: I have edited the code base. FVConfigProvider has register method through which all the mime types are being registered.

Comment: Got a solution. Register as '*' and all the mime types will be registered. Although this was mine specific requirement, might help some one.